# Declaring Functions in Groovy

Tags: java, function, groovy

I am trying to declare the following function in Groovy that should return a string.

```
def String sortCharacters(String string) {
    char[] charArray = string.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(charArray);
    return String.valueOf(charArray)
}
```

For some reason, I am getting an error when trying to use it on a string.

```
string1.sortCharacters(string1);

No signature of method: java.lang.String.sortCharacters() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot invoke this method on `String` object, but int the following way:

```
sortCharacters(string1)
```

or

```
string1 = sortCharacters(string1)
```

If You'd like to add `sortCharacters` to `String` class itself it can be done int the following way:

```
String.metaClass.sortCharacters = {
    char[] charArray = delegate.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(charArray)
    return String.valueOf(charArray)
}

assert 'abz' == 'bza'.sortCharacters()
```

Comment: They also don't need `def String`

Comment: You could also just do `string.toLowerCase().toList().sort().join()` ;-)

Comment: Not too much at once ;)